# Springer Nature Template Bug: How to make references to tables in appendix work?

Tags: tables, cross-referencing, appendices, springernature

[Here](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/springer-nature-latex-template/gsvvftmrppwq) is the Springer Nature template on Overleaf, [here](https://www.springernature.com/gp/authors/campaigns/latex-author-support) is the download version.

I can reference a table from an appendix and the displayed name is correct (e.g. Table A1), however, the **hyperlink is false** and directs me to Table 1 rather than Table A1.

MWE using Springer Nature template:

```
\documentclass[pdflatex,sn-mathphys]{sn-jnl}

\begin{document}
\section{Test references}\label{sec_intro}
Table \ref{tab} in Section \ref{sec_tables}. Table \ref{tab-test} in Appendix \ref{secA1}.

\newpage
\section{Normal section}\label{sec_tables}
\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Caption text}\label{tab}%
X
\end{table}

\newpage
\begin{appendices}
\section{Appendix}\label{secA1}
\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Caption text}\label{tab-test}%
X
\end{table}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

I'm thankful for any hint. I assume it's a problem with the `sn-jnl.cls` but I'm not confident at all.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I assume it's a problem with the `sn-jnl.cls`.

Correct.

The Springer template in question appears to modify the appearance of the `section` counter and resets the counters for sections, equations, tables, and figures to zero when the `appendices` environment is entered. However, the template evidently fails to take care of adquately informing the `hyperref` package -- which, incidentally, is loaded automatically by the document class -- about this change.

The workaround? Insert the instruction

```
\renewcommand\theHtable{AABB\arabic{table}}
```

immediately after `\begin{appendices}`. Here, "AABB" is simply any unique string. See section 5.2., "Options for destination names", of the user guide of the [hyperref](https://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) package for more information on this topic.

If, in addition, you also have `figure` environments in the appendix and wish to cross-reference them elsewhere in the document, be sure to run

```
\renewcommand\theHfigure{AABB\arabic{figure}}
```

as well.

[image]

```
\documentclass[pdflatex,sn-mathphys]{sn-jnl}

\begin{document}

\section{Test references}\label{sec_intro}

Table \ref{tab} in Section \ref{sec_tables}. 
Table \ref{tab-testA} in Appendix \ref{sec:AppA}.


\newpage
\section{Normal section}\label{sec_tables}

\begin{table}[h] \caption{Caption text}\label{tab} XYZ \end{table}

\newpage
\begin{appendices}

%% For use with 'hyperref': Choose a unique identifier, e.g., 
%%   the string 'AABB', to redefine the '\theHtable' macro
\renewcommand\theHtable{AABB\arabic{table}} % <-- new

\section{Supplemental Material}\label{sec:AppA}
\begin{table}[h] \caption{Caption text}\label{tab-testA} UVW \end{table}

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, works like a charm.
So happy I don't need to change the template cls file!